# google.com is not opening on mozilla firefox on ubuntu

Tags: firefox, certificates

Trying to open google.com in mozilla firefox in ubuntu ,getting the message

**"This Connection is Untrusted"**
so i clicked on  **"I understand the risk"** then 
**"Add exception"**
and then
**"Confirm security exception"**

Still same error is coming

When i open the certificate ,The heading is 
**"Could not verify this certificate because the issuer is unknown**"

Comment: please check this post [might](http://superuser.com/questions/452063/the-certificate-is-not-trusted-because-no-issuer-chain-was-provided) be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because of proxy, you can change it as "No Proxy". Go to

```
preference >> Advanced >> Network >> Settings >>"No proxy"
```